# Datastore - Allocate ids with max length

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I want to auto generate ids in cloud datastore that doesn't exceed more than 7 digits in length.

In previous version of python cloud datastore library one was able to provide a max parameter to ensure that the auto generated id doesn't exceed a maximum limit.
Ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys

Since now this feature has been removed from the latest python datastore library:
Ref: https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/client.html#Client.key

How can one achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to achieve that, unfortunately, in the newest version. As the official documentation confirms [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrate-to-cloud-ndb#queries), there isn't a replacement for the method `max_allocate_ids_keys()`, so it's not possible to limit the size of the id, which as you probably know, can be up to 16 digits.

If you find it useful, you can raise a Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187197&template=0), on Google's Issue Tracker, so they can check about possibly implementing a similar feature in new versions.